# Does $\sum^{\infty}_1 k \tan(1/k^3)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to determine if $$\sum^{\infty}_1 k \tan(1/k^3)$$ converges.

Since $1/k^3 \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, I'm thinking that all the terms will be positive, so I'm thinking the alternating series test is out of the question. I'm trying to think of an appropriate series to compare it to, but I am not sure what to compare a tan-series to! Do I compare it to another tan-series or something else? Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to compare it to $\sum1/k^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using $\sin(x)\le x$ for $x>0$, we note that for $0<x<1$, $$\tan(x)\le x/\cos(1)$$

What happens when you set $x=1/k^3$?

Comment: Why do you write $\cos(1)$? Or do you mean $\cos(x) = 1$?

Comment: $\cos(x)\ge \cos(1)$ for $x\in (0,1)$.  So, $\frac1{\cos(x)}\le \frac1{\cos(1)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Asymptotically $$\tan\left( \frac{1}{k^3}\right)\sim \frac{1}{k^3}$$

Comment: You  should  add this is an asymptotic equivalence

Comment: Yes, I tried that so I would get $k \tan(1/k^3) \sim 1/k^2$ but isn't $k \tan(1/k^3) \geq 1/k^2$? So I don't know how I can use that as a comparison.... Am I missing something?

Comment: @user9750060 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: @Bernard. Whether your statement applies to me or to OP and whether it is the basis of minus?

Comment: @zkutch: I didn't downvote (I never do). I only meant that, as I  undertand you hint, you used asymptotic equivalence, in the exacts sense of equivalent functions is asymptotic analysis. There's a result asserting that two series with equivalent general terms both converge or both diverge – and $\dfrac1{k^2}$ is a convergent $p$-series.

Comment: @Bernard. Thanks for explanation. Let me say, that sign "$\sim$" in mathematical analysis and its brothers **by default** mean asymptotic notation,  when speech is about series convergence.

Comment: I think so. Personally, to avoid any ambiguity, I denote it  `\sim_{\infty}`. B.t.w. I think you're were downvoted by the same maniac who downvotes many of my own answers when I propose a solution based on asymptotic analysis.

Comment: Who did downvote? Why should someone do this for a hint? +

Comment: @Mikasa. Thanks for +. As wrote Bernard here somewhere is "maniac who downvotes ...solution based on asymptotic analysis". Of course if he/she have arguments, then he/she would give them, but prefer to live in darkness.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Taylor Series for $Tan(x)$, substituting $\frac{1}{k^3}$ for $x$, multiplying by k, and then summing yields the equivalent series:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2 \cdot (2^{2k}-1)}{\pi^{2k}} \zeta(2k)
\zeta(6k-4) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot Tan(\frac{1}{k^3}) $

Using the ratio test for the left hand side yields $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$ which is less than one. Therefore the series converges absolutely.

Comment: You nicely accelarated the convergence. Just a minor remark: I would put the multiplier $2$ in front of $2^{2k}-1$. For a minute I thought it was a square which would make the series divergent.

Comment: @Gary Thank you and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible hint:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{2}\times a_n=1<\infty.$$ So, according to Quotient test, it converges.